# Number rings with elements of norm $-1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is there a nice characterization of number rings $\mathcal{O}$ such that there exists an element $x \in \mathcal{O}$ whose norm is $-1$?

One obvious necessary condition is that $\mathcal{O}$ must have a real embedding.  For real quadratic number rings, norm $-1$ elements sometimes exist and sometimes don't.  For instance:

**Example**: In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, the norm of $1+\sqrt{2}$ is $-1$.

**Example**: In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, there is no element of norm $-1$.  Indeed, the norm of $a+b\sqrt{3}$ is $a^2-3b^2$.  If this were $-1$, then we would have that $a^2 \equiv -1$ mod $3$, which is impossible.

Comment: So I see that someone downvoted this question.  I apologize for not phrasing it in terms of $\infty$-categories or stacks or whatever.  But I'm pretty certain it is not elementary or easy (though my own research is in topology rather than number theory, so I might not be aware of the relevant literature; this came up in some calculations I was making).

Comment: Hi Tina, Welcome to MO. I didn't downvote, but I will note that the question of characterizing which real quadratic fields have an element of norm $-1$ is a long-standing open conjecture on which little progress has been made. For that reason, it may be viewed as inappropriate on MO, where there is a policy that one shouldn't ask about longstanding open problems. That might explain the downvote. In any case, if you add the word "known" to your question, i.e., "Is there a known nice characterization...", then the answer, unfortunately, is no.

Comment: @JoeSilverman: Thanks!  I certainly agree that intentionally asking well-known open problems is pointless and silly, but there is of course no central repository of well-known problems.  I always thought one of the main purposes of MO is for mathematicians to ask questions about topics outside their main fields of interest (but which e.g. arise in their research).  It seems unfriendly to downvote someone in that situation just because they happened to stumble upon something that is notorious to the experts.

Comment: What Joe said, but at least a few things can be said about the quadratic case. $x^2-Dy^2=-1$ can't have a solution unless $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $D$, so that rules out any $D$ divisible by a prime congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. There's a very partial converse – if $p$ is a prime congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, then there are solutions to $x^2-py^2=-1$. $D=34$ is (if I remember right) the smallest example where $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $D$ ($13^2\equiv-1\bmod{34}$) but $x^2-Dy^2=-1$ has no solution, as can be seen using the continued fraction for $\sqrt{34}$.

Comment: Tina, I agree with you, many "well-known" open problems are only well-known to people in that field, and I agree  that MO is a good place for people in other fields to find out about them. But not everyone agrees, and since you're listed as a new contributor and seemed to wonder why the down-vote(s), I thought I'd try to explain the likely reason. But I should also have said "but don't worry about a down-vote or two." And as you can see by the up-votes, there are definitely people who appreciate your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks!  Do you know a reference for the "partial converse" concerning primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$?

Comment: Not offhand, Tina, but it may be in one of the better Intro Number Theory textbooks.

Comment: It's problem 12 in Section 7.8, Pell's Equation, in Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery, An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, 5th ed.

Comment: It's also Exercise 15 in Chapter 17, Diophantine Equations, in Ireland and Rosen, A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks!

Comment: By Hasse norm theorem, if $K$ is a finite cyclic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$,(in particular $K$ is a quadratic field) then $-1$ is a norm of some element of $K$ if and only if $-1$ is a local norm everywhere. However, I think giving a satisfied  characterization of number rings $O_K$ such that there exists an element $x\in O_K$ whose norm is $−1$ is very difficult.